# Extract text between tags containing a given word using Python

Tags: python, xml, nlp

I have some text from an XML document where I am trying to extract the text within tags contain certain words.

For example below:

```
search('adverse')
```

should return the text of all the tags containing the word 'adverse'

```
Out: 
  [
    "<item>The most common adverse reactions reported in subjects receiving coadministered dutasteride and tamsulosin were impotence, decreased libido, breast disorders (including breast enlargement and tenderness), ejaculation disorders, and dizziness.</item>"
  ]
```

and `search('clinical')`

should return two results since two tags contain those words.

```
Out: 
  [
    "<title>6.1 Clinical Trials Experience</title>", 
    "<paragraph id="ID41">The clinical efficacy and safety of coadministered dutasteride and tamsulosin, which are individual components of dutasteride and tamsulosin hydrochloride capsules, have been evaluated in a multicenter, randomized, double-blind, parallel group trial (the Combination with Alpha-Blocker Therapy, or CombAT, trial) </paragraph>"
  ]
```

What tools should I use for this? RegEx? BS4? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

---

Example Text:

```
 </highlight>
 </excerpt>
 <component>
 <section id="ID40">
 <id root="fbc21d1a-2fb2-47b1-ac53-f84ed1428bb4"></id>
 <title>6.1 Clinical Trials Experience</title>
 <text>
 <paragraph id="ID41">The clinical efficacy and safety of coadministered dutasteride and tamsulosin, which are individual components of dutasteride and tamsulosin hydrochloride capsules, have been evaluated in a multicenter, randomized, double-blind, parallel group trial (the Combination with Alpha-Blocker Therapy, or CombAT, trial) </paragraph>
 <list id="ID42" listtype="unordered" stylecode="Disc">
 <item>The most common adverse reactions reported in subjects receiving coadministered dutasteride and tamsulosin were impotence, decreased libido, breast disorders (including breast enlargement and tenderness), ejaculation disorders, and dizziness.</item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either hardcode it with a regex, or parse your xml file with a library like [lxml](https://lxml.de/)

With a regex that would be:

```
import re

your_text = "(...)"

def search(instr):
    return re.findall(r"<.+>.*{}.*<.+>".format(instr), your_text, re.MULTILINE)

print(search("safety"))
```